# *args and **kwargs in python

Tags: python, new-operator, super, argv, keyword-argument

I premit that I am begginer with *args and **kwargs. I was trying to make some mock code imitating what I have seen been doing in this forum and elsewhere on the net. However, when I have tried to do something similar to what I have seen, I received an unexpected error. This is the example:

```py
class A():
    defined = []
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new = kwargs['new']
        if not new and len(A.defined)>0:
            x = A.defined[0]
        else:
            # x = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            # if I use this, it raises error: 
            # "TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)"
            x = super().__new__(cls)
            # this works
        return x

    def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value = value
        A.defined.append(self) 

a = A("a", new = True)
```

Why is there this error?

Thanks.

Comment: The formatting of the code is a bit off... Please [edit] that and include the full error output from running exactly the code you post here. Also, I wonder, are `*args` and `**kwargs` actually relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1):

when you use `super().__new__` it is the `__new__` method of `object` class, which takes exactly one argument (`cls`). since you are also forwarding to it the `*args, **kwargs` arguments, you are basically sending `(cls, new=True)` to a method that expects only `(cls)`

hope that makes sense